# SpriteKit: is it possible for two runActions to run serially as part of the same sequence?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

One of the answers in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987153/ios-spritekit-skaction-completion-call-not-working-creating-odd-results?rq=1) suggests that two `runAction` blocks belonging to the same `SKAction.sequence` will run simultaneously. This is also consistent with our experience.

Is it possible to make multiple `runAction` blocks run linearly instead of simultaneously, even if all belong to the same `SKAction.sequence`?

And specifically, is it possible in Swift?

Comment: So do you need to convert the link you provided?

Comment: @Jesster2k10 No, this is a conceptual question because we're seeing the same issue with our code (Swift). If it's a limitation of the language, it would be helpful to know. Do you know the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will run simultaneously. If I want to run them linearly then I need to know the duration of the first action.  I add an `SKAction.waitForDuration()` in between the two actions using the duration of the first action.

Runaction is really meant to be used with one node running single, groups, or sequences of skactions.  It's not meant to be run in a sequence itself